# OpenERP 7 : How to trigger a auto version increase function after click save

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

how could i trigger a function after i click save in OpenERP 7?

In my custom module, i wish to auto increase the "version_number" parameter where every time the user click save it will trigger a function to execute the logic of "ver=ver+1" and write back to the "version_number" fields. How could i do that?

I tried use "def write()" but not sure exactly how it could be done. Appreciate your kind help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `write` method.

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    res = super(your_model, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context)
    self._increment_version(cr, uid, ids)
    return res

def _increment_version(self, cr, uid, ids):
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        cr.execute('update table_name set version_number=%s where id=%s' % (record.version_number + 1, record.id))
```

Comment: I prefer your answer, because it is more complete. But with Odoo's old browse objects your last line can produce an error, if the browse would return a browse_null object.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: First `ids` could be an integer, second ids could have wrong ids or is None. Your code would try to get `version_number` from a browse_null object and that will give an error.

Comment: @CZoellner, i tried. It seem Rawly idea is working better but require slight modification. i encounter error for the statement "for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):" and i further change it to reads = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['version'], context=context) and capture version using ver_num = reads.get('version')

Comment: @Samleecomp his last edited version seems ok, whereas i wouldn't prefer use of direct cursor execution. Instead i would do `record.write({'version_number': record.version_number + 1})' at the last line.

Comment: @CZoellner, i think through your recommendation this weekend and modified it according to your suggestion (direct cursor execution might not be encourage). Ultimately it work well. My previous error is due to the  ids error which causing unable to run "for record in self browse"where it should be [ids] instead of integer ids. Again thank you Rawly and you.

Comment: @Samleecomp Glad to help you (upvote for answring you question).

Answer (score 1):

you are right you should use write function as.

```py
    _columns={...,
          'ver':fields.integer(),
        ...}

    def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None)
        vals['ver']= trigger_func()
        return self.super(your_class_name).write(cr, uid, vals, context)
```

**EDIT**
It looks like my answer was not clear enough sorry if I didn't check the comments at the time. But because the problem and solutions are the same in newer versions of odoo/openerp, I am adding more description here.

The `trigger_func` must not write any value to the db (no `self.write` or `self.some_field=some_value`). It should simply return the new value for version.

```py
def trigger_func(self):
    return self.ver + 1
```

for newer version of Odoo (V8+), use the same format for trigger function and:

```py
@api.multi
def write(self,vals):
     vals['ver'] = self.trigger_func()
     return super(YourClassName, self).write(vals)
```

Please note that this will set the same version for all records, You should use `self.ensure_one()` at the beginning of the `trigger_func` if you plan to change versions record by record. If you want a solution that works for multi writes (which I do recommend change your code to avoid it) you can use this slower code:

```py
@api.multi
def write(self,vals):
    if len(self)>1:
        for rec in self:
            rec.write(vals)
        return self
    else:
        vals['ver'] = self.trigger_func()
        return super(YourClassName, self).write(vals)
```

Another solution if you want to add version number to all models, would be patching the Abstract class and adding an auto increase magic field but it looks very overkill for this purpose.

Anyway, I think the direct use of the cursor should be the last resort.

Comment: i having an issue where enter infinity loop which trigger by self.super(your_class_name).write(cr, uid, vals, context)  where it keep calling the def write. Any idea how to only execute it one time only?

Comment: @Samleecomp Because you call`write()` method in `trigger_func()`.When you call `write()` from `write()` you obviously end up with recursion.Try using `cr.execute()`.Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675460/openerp-7-how-to-trigger-a-auto-version-increase-function-after-click-save/38683482#38683482

Comment: @Samleecomp What if `len(ids)>1` ?.

Comment: @Rawly it is not the issue of len(ids), it is due to it keep calling back the write. Anyway i found solution for it now. You are right, i using cr.execute of your proposed method, it seem working but have slightly error where in write it cannot call "for record xxxx". I had modified it and will post it later. Again thanks, you are indeed helpful

Comment: Guys, In my solution you will not have loop, because `trigger_func` is not supposed to write any value into the database, it should just return the new value for version. Then we put this value in the `vals` dictionary and we call `super.write` with this new value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the  `write` method work for me

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    res = super(your_model, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context)
    self._increment_version(cr, uid, ids)
    return res

def _increment_version(self, cr, uid, ids):
    res = {}
    reads = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['version'], context=context)
    ver_num = reads.get('version')
    ver_id = reads.get('id')
    if ver_num:        
        cr.execute('update table_name set version_number=%s where id=%s' % (ver_num + 1, ver_id))
    return res
```